# Toggle us_intl and another layout

Tags: keyboard-layout, xkb

I write on day to day basis in English, German and Spanish which can be wonderfully handled using the US layout with the internationl variant (actually altgr-intl).

The problem occurs when I wanna write in my native language, Hebrew. If I add it to a dual toggle mode with an US international keymap the us intl breaks and becomes a normal US keymap.

To clarify:

While this command works as expected:

```
setxkbmap -rules evdev -model evdev -layout us -variant altgr-intl
```

This command sadly doesn't:

```
setxkbmap -rules evdev -model evdev -layout us,il -variant altgr-intl -option grp:alt_shift_toggle
```

Answer (score 1):

Well, I found a less-than-perfect solution; using ibus instead of pure xkb. The ibus method handles both layouts correctly.

I'll post a bug report and see what they think. Maybe I'm doing something wrong but I can't see what exactly.

Answer (score 1):

So the xkb way is a bit confusing but this is how it works: the "us,il" following the -layout flag is a tuple and so in that case the -variant flag would expect a tuple as well. Therefore a command for both layouts could be:

```
setxkbmap -layout us,il -variant altgr-intl, -option grp:alt_shift_toggle
```

Note the comma after altgr-intl.